# Como cambiar el color y forma de un input checkbox en HTML cuando sea clickeado

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, input, checkbox

Cordial saludo:

Estoy haciendo un .html con bootstrap y me gustaría modificar la forma y color de como se muestra el checkbox cuando es valido o no.

Me gustaría algo como en la siguiente gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo el siguiente input:

```
<div class="form-check ageAlert">
    <input class="form-check-input btnCheckYellow" type="checkbox" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
    > de 15<br>< de 40
    </label>
</div>
```

con el siguiente css:

```
.btnCheckYellow{
    background: yellow;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.ageAlert{
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

Alguien podría de darme una idea de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario usar otro elemento para lograr el objetivo, puedes personalizar sin problemas un elemento [`checkbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) usando sólo CSS.

Para ello debes primero eliminar el estilo que provee el navegador usando la propiedad CSS [`appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) y establecer su valor a `none`. De esta forma los estilos propios del navegador (que dependen en gran medida del sistema operativo) no serán aplicados al elemento `checkbox` y podrás poner tus propios estilos.

Por ejemplo, si deseo tener un `checkbox` que se muestre como un círculo amarillo, podría hacer lo siguiente:

```css
.custom-checkbox {
    /* Elimino los estilos del navegaror */
    appearance: none;
    /* Aplico mis estilos */
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Para añadir la barra invertida que deseas que el elemento muestre cuando su estado es `checked`, debes usar la pseudo clase [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:checked). En este caso, usaremos un [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient), por ejemplo:

```css
.custom-checkbox:checked {
    background:linear-gradient(315deg, yellow 45%, black 45%, black 55%, yellow 55%, yellow 100%);
}
```

El código completo funcional puede verse así:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.custom-checkbox {
    appearance: none;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.custom-checkbox:checked {
    background:linear-gradient(315deg, yellow 45%, black 45%, black 55%, yellow 55%, yellow 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <label>Custom checkbox</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="custom-checkbox" />
</div>
```

Basta que ajustes el tamaño y otros elementos que se ajusten a tus estilos o tema.

Comment: Muchas gracias... eres un genio, Me funcionó perfectamente.

Answer (score 2):

La tecnica para lograr esto es:

1. Ocultar el input
2. Ligar el `input` oculto a un `label` mediante el atributo `for`, de esta manera el acto de presionar el label es lo mismo que presionar el `input`
3. Luego en el `label` colocar todos los CSS necesario para mostrarlo como deseamos
4. Además podemos usar una regla como esta `.labelcheck:checked + label` para ingresar CSS adicional para el caso que el checkbox está checkado
5. Para tu caso particular, es posible generar una línea transversal usando `linear-gradient`

   ```css
   .labelcheck{
    display:none;
   }
   .labelcheck + label{
       background-color: yellow;
       width:20px;
       height:20px;
       display: inline-block;
       border-radius: 50%;
       cursor:pointer;
   }

   .labelcheck:checked + label{
         background-image:linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 40%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, transparent 60%);

   }
   ```

   ```html
   <input type="checkbox" class="labelcheck" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
   <label for="flexRadioDefault1">
   </label>
   ```